# Font Awesome not displaying on mobile

Tags: css, media-queries

I created a website and uploaded it now on my server. My problem is that I used font awesome; on local and PC it works but on mobile it does not. I tested on Chrome and Mozilla on HTC 10.

my CSS:

```
.back_to_top {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal normal normal 26px/1 FontAwesome;
    -webkit-opacity: .5;
    -moz-opacity: .5;
    -ms-opacity: .5;
    -o-opacity: .5;
    opacity: .5;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f2735a;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-text-decoration: none;
    -moz-text-decoration: none;
    -ms-text-decoration: none;
    -o-text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    display: none
}

.back_to_top:after {
    content: '\f062';
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

Here's the arrow http://fontawesome.io/icon/arrow-up/

My page you can try: http://zakopane-rzadkosz.pl

Comment: Please add your html.

Comment: Hmmm but actually i have that in my lightbox too and it's the same

Comment: It's not working on desktop either because the font files are returning a 404 error. Check your console.

Comment: Yup that's the problem, i didn't upload a folder with fonts thank you!! u can add answer and i will confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your console, you'll see the following error referring to your CSS files.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Make sure the files are uploaded and the `<link>` tag is pointing to the correct file path.